# How to choose multiple table structure for fastest query response

Tags: mysql, performance, multiple-tables

I have a database in which I am listing events by geography (currently around 100000 events in the database). At the moment it's in a nicely normalised schema: an event in table `tevent` has a foreign key `fkvenue` which points at a venue in table `tvenue` which has a foreign key `fkcity`, and so on to `tregion` and `tcountry`.

The query to find the countries with the most events is therefore fairly complex, with no less than three inner joins:

`select r.fkcountry,count(distinct e.id) from tevent e 
inner join tvenue v on e.fkvenue=v.id
inner join tcity cy on v.fkcity=cy.id
inner join tregion r on cy.fkregion=r.id
group by r.fkcountry order by count(distinct e.id) desc`

I'm trying to find ways of speeding things up, and I thought it might be helpful to map the events directly by country. I've created a map table `teventcountry`, with the following much simpler resulting syntax:

`select ec.fkcountry,count(distinct e.id) from tevent e inner join teventcountry ec on ec.fkevent=e.id group by ec.fkcountry order by count(distinct e.id) desc`

To my surprise, this had the exact opposite effect: the new query took nearly five times as long as the older, much more complex query.

Can someone explain this, or point me at a good resource to help me gain an understanding of the speed of multi-table queries? Or even tell me a preferred pattern for this sort of thing?

(before anyone asks, I've taken care to do a "reset query cache" between runs in order to make the timing results valid, and yes, I have indexed everything properly!!!!)

Thanks

David

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at how MySQL is evaluating the queries. To do this, use the built-in command `EXPLAIN`, which describes how MySQL executes a given select statement.

Here is the reference on EXPLAIN: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/explain.html

You can use EXPLAIN's output to see the MySQL "query execution plan", including which indexes and joins it would use, and so on. From this you can interpret why a given query is fast or slow, and what you can do to improve it. Usually this means adding a particular index, or tweaking one so it can be used in your query.

You can Google "MySQL EXPLAIN" for a bunch of guides on using this powerful tool. Here is one such walk-through: http://forums.spry.com/howtos/1345-using-mysqls-explain-command.html